# unsafe value used in a resource URL context

Tags: node.js, angular, angular6

I'm new to Angular 6 and I'm getting this error:

> "unsafe value used in a resource URL context (see
>   http://g.co/ng/security#xss)"

I have searched allot and found that to fix this issue need to create a pipe in angular which i did and created new pipe then changed code in html but still issue persists can any person guide me?

[image: This is the error which I'm getting]

Changed Iframe code as show below after creating new pipe:

```
 <iframe src="http://localhost:8087/bim/api/v1/dashboardTree/{{companyId}} |safe"></iframe>
```

The code of the pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'tree'
})
export class TreePipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  transform(url) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`src` attribute is a string, a pipe isn't evaluated there. In order for it to be evaluated as an expression, it should be:

```
<iframe [src]="('http://localhost:8087/bim/api/v1/dashboardTree/' + companyId) | safe"></iframe>
```

Also, there's an inconsistency, the pipe is `safe` in one place and `tree` in another.